# How to get the adress based on Geo coordinates and vice versa

Tags: geolocation

i would like to use geo coordinates in my application for locating the users current position and city. I have the longtitude and latitude.

How can match a geo coordinate to a city oder vice versa?

Is there any database which i can use (for offline usage e.g.)? Or use any service which provides this?

What are large social apps using for this problem?

br
Yavuz

Comment: Google has some api.

Comment: Google's GEO location API https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

Comment: Ok, sounds good. But do you think that solutions with very high traffic are using such services, too?  Or is there even a way to have such data locally in the database?